# Why error C6386 buffer overrun with strsafe.h StringCch functions?

Tags: c++, winapi, tchar, buffer-overrun, strsafe

So I ran an Analyze in VS 2017 with my C++ code. It gives me a buffer overrun with the following:

```
TCHAR *sTemp = new TCHAR[5]();
if (sTemp)
    StringCchCopy(sTemp, 5, L"0123456789");
```

When I step through the code, sTemp is "0123", with the 4th position of course being \0.

When I run Analyze on the code, I get the C6386 error:

> Warning   C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'sTemp':  the writable size is 'unsigned int' bytes, but '10' bytes might be written.

Why? I have also tried changing the array to 10 and the StringCchCopy to 5 and still the same error.

Comment: It's not an error, but a warning

Comment: Presumably because the static analyse cannot verify the size of the buffer. Declare it as `TCHAR sTemp[5]` instead. Also, give up on `TCHAR` unless you need to support Windows 98.

Comment: Yeah, just habit of TCHAR. All unicode. Wonder why it can't verify the size?

Comment: Presumably because the buffer is dynamically allocated and the tool doesn't perform data flow analysis. But why are you punishing yourself anyway? Just use `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 0):

The warning refers to the fact, that the source string will not ever fit inside the destination. The source string has a length of 10, the destination a size of 5 code units. It's not relevant at all, that the static analyzer cannot determine the size of the dynamically allocated destination array.

If it were, and it would discover a mismatch between the actual size and the size you claimed, it would raise an error, not a warning.

Answer (score -1):

The docs for StringCchCopy say that the second parameter must be the size of the destination buffer *and* that the destination buffer must be big enough to hold the source string. You're not checking the return code from the function but I suspect it will be STRSAFE_E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER, which means "The copy operation failed due to insufficient buffer space. The destination buffer contains a truncated, null-terminated version of the intended result. In situations where truncation is acceptable, this may not necessarily be seen as a failure condition."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strsafe/nf-strsafe-stringcchcopyw

I guess you're happy with, and expecting, the truncation, but the static analysis tool is seeing that your source string is longer than your destination buffer and triggering the warning.

Comment: I'm sceptical of this. The warning message seems to indicate that the tool can't verify the size of the buffer. *the writable size is 'unsigned int' bytes* would indicate that the tool has no idea of the size of the buffer.